# How to separate chars in groups of 20 characters in C code

Tags: c, string, char

In C, I'm trying to split the sentence stored into a char "Hi, my name is David. What is your name?" into 20 character lines:

"Hi, my name is David"

". What is your name?"

At first, I was thinking of using a for loop to print out each character separately, however, I came to realize that I would only print the first 20 chars... Are there any suggestions for what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `strncpy` in a loop:

```
const char* str = "Hi, my name is David. What is your name?";

const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 20;
size_t len = strlen(str);
size_t pos = 0;
while (pos < len)
{
     char tmp[CHUNK_SIZE+1];            //+1 to leave room for null termination
     strncpy(tmp, str+pos, CHUNK_SIZE);
     tmp[CHUNK_SIZE] = '\0';            //null terminate end of buffer if needed
     pos += CHUNK_SIZE;
     printf("%s\n", tmp);
}
```

And if you only need to print the substring, you can avoid the tmp buffer and strncpy thing altogether. Let `printf` with a precision specifier do the heavy work for you:

```
const char* str = "Hi, my name is David. What is your name?";

const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 20;
size_t len = strlen(str);
size_t pos = 0;
while (pos < len)
{
    printf("%.20s\n", str + pos);
    pos += CHUNK_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this problem since yesterday!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and/or accept it.